# Multiplying a [int(x) for x in input().split()]

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I'm getting 2 integers and want to multiply them straight away. I do:

`X,Y = [int(x) for x in input().split()]`

But can't really make out how to multiply them without creating a new line and just using a third variable like this:

`W = X*Y`

Can someone point me out how to do that? I've tried to look for a function like sum() since it creates a list. I can't use any libraries

Comment: can you provide an specific example of what your input is?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since this is probably an attempt to solve a challenge on a programming website I assume that readability is not a top priority, you can use [`reduce`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functools.html#functools.reduce) (and [`map`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#map) to get rid of the explicit loop):

```
from functools import reduce

print(reduce(lambda a, b: a * b, map(int, input().split())))
```

The bonus is that this works for any arbitrary amount of numbers separated with spaces.

Comment: Readability isn't important, but I can't use libraries.

Comment: @Rafael_O `functools` is s built-in module, so you can.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`math.prod`](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/math.html#math.prod):

```py
from math import prod

w = prod(int(x) for x in input().split())
print(w)
```

Prints (for example):

```
3 5
15
```

---

EDIT: Without libraries:

```py
def my_prod(i, start=1):
    out = start
    for v in i:
        out *= v
    return out


w = my_prod(int(x) for x in input().split())
print(w)
```

Comment: Really good solution, but I unfortunately can't use libraries

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Python 3.8+, you can use `prod` from `math` module as follows:

```
from math import prod

w = prod(int(x) for x in input().split())
```

For a prior version, you should use `reduce` from `functools` module:

```py
from functools import reduce # this line is mandatory in Python 3
import operator

def prod(iterable):
    return reduce(operator.mul, iterable, 1)


w = prod(int(x) for x in input().split())
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you want to do:

```
eval('*'.join([x for x in input().split()]))
```